# Buffer overflow attack not going as intended

Tags: c, x86, buffer-overflow, machine-code, eip

I was watching this video on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1S0aBV-Waeo and i was trying to do the same steps shown in the video, but i can't seem to overwrite the EIP. I don't know if it's because the gdb may have changed during the years, or if anything else has. What i get when i try to overflow is the following

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x080491ac in main (
    argc=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x41414141>, 
    argv=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x41414145>)
    at example.c:9
9   }
```

and not what you normally see in these buffer overflow exploit videos

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000414141414141 in ?? ()
```

I can't seem to overwrite the eip, no matter how large my input is. The code is the same as shown in the video with a smaller buffer size.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char buffer[10];
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

I also get asked the following when running my program in gdb for the first time.

```
This GDB supports auto-downloading debuginfo from the following URLs:
  <https://debuginfod.archlinux.org>
Enable debuginfod for this session? (y or [n])
```

This is the register info in gdb.

```
Breakpoint 2, 0x08049196 in main (argc=2, argv=0xffffd434) at example.c:6
6       strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
(gdb) info reg
eax            0x804bff4           134529012
ecx            0xffffd380          -11392
edx            0xffffd356          -11434
ebx            0x804bff4           134529012
esp            0xffffd340          0xffffd340
ebp            0xffffd368          0xffffd368
esi            0xffffd440          -11200
edi            0xf7ffcb60          -134231200
eip            0x8049196           0x8049196 <main+48>
eflags         0x296               [ PF AF SF IF ]
cs             0x23                35
ss             0x2b                43
ds             0x2b                43
es             0x2b                43
fs             0x0                 0
gs             0x63                99
(gdb) x/20x $esp
0xffffd340: 0xffffd356  0xffffd676  0x00000000  0x0804917d
0xffffd350: 0xffffffff  0xf7d833d4  0xf7fc1380  0x00000000
0xffffd360: 0xffffd380  0xf7f95e2c  0x00000000  0xf7d96af9
0xffffd370: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x080482e7  0xf7d96af9
0xffffd380: 0x00000002  0xffffd434  0xffffd440  0xffffd3a0
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, main (
    argc=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x41414141>, 
    argv=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x41414145>)
    at example.c:9
9   }

(gdb) x/20x $esp
0xffffd350: 0xffffffff  0x414133d4  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xffffd360: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xffffd370: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xffffd380: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141
0xffffd390: 0x41414141  0x41414141  0x41414141  0xffff0041
(gdb) info reg
eax            0x0                 0
ecx            0x41414141          1094795585
edx            0xffffd390          -11376
ebx            0x41414141          1094795585
esp            0x4141413d          0x4141413d
ebp            0x41414141          0x41414141
esi            0xffffd440          -11200
edi            0xf7ffcb60          -134231200
eip            0x80491ac           0x80491ac <main+70>
eflags         0x10286             [ PF SF IF RF ]
cs             0x23                35
ss             0x2b                43
ds             0x2b                43
es             0x2b                43
fs             0x0                 0
gs             0x63                99
```

I'm compiling with the following flags

```
gcc -o example2 -fno-stack-protector -no-pie -m32 -g -z execstack example2.c -w
```